# How to say "make use of something" in german?

Tags: english-to-german

I've translated this phrase like below but I'm not sure does it make sense. I'll appreciate any help especially on bold typed part. Because I stumble upon this for the first time.

In contrast with the deductive method, inductive instruction **makes use of student “noticing”.**(Im Gegensatz zu der deduktiven Methode,induktive Einführung **macht Gebrauch von Schüler "Bemerkung".**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> von etw. Gebrauch machen

is indeed one of the possible translations of "*make use of sth.*". Nonetheless, it does not really fit in your actual context. If you want to express "*make use of sth.*" in a sense of **exploiting**, you must use:

> etw. ausnutzen

Further, your translations of "noticing" and "instruction" are not really correct either. I think it must be sth. like

> Im Gegensatz zur deduktiven Methode, nutzt induktiver Unterricht das
>   schülerische "Begreifen"  aus.

I'm not 100% sure whether this is a correct translation of "noticing", since it's a special term used in teaching.

Comment: Good suggestions. Perhaps "Wahrnehmen" or "Wahrnehmungen" could be another option for "noticing".  (It's more literal and fits with the [original article's](http://www.educ.ualberta.ca/staff/olenka.bilash/best%20of%20bilash/inductivedeductive.html) explanation: "[the students] come to understand the rule by noticing what those examples have in common.") Ah, and the comma after "Methode" is superfluous.

Comment: The comma in the 3rd suggestion is wrong: Im Gegensatz zur deduktiven Methode nutzt induktiver Unterricht ...